# Fail on booting Ubuntu 20.04 installation USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, 20.04

I'm using Windows 10 and trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop using a bootable USB drive.

I received this error message before the loading page shows up: "Failure creating named object" with some firmware bug.

[image: Screenshot here]

It always forces a shutdown after the loading reaches 3%.

[image: Screenshot here]

I tried updating my BIOS to the latest version.

Comment: What model Asus? You need either safe graphics boot or nomodeset boot parameter if nVidia graphics. Should be similar as vendors often use same UEFI:. Acer Aspire 5 Model A515-54-5649  Intel Core i5-10210U Install Tutorial
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by setting nouveau.modeset = 0 before install and then install nvidia driver after the installation process is done.

Here’s link to the tutorial:
https://medium.com/@nitinpatel_20236/fixing-the-problems-installing-ubuntu-on-asus-rog-laptop-asus-gl503ge-5b6f497201b8